Does gravity cause energy to exist?
I may be fundamentally misunderstanding Poincare symmetry, but does the curvature of spacetime due to energy generate the topological conditions required to satisfy the translational time symmetry of energy?

A de Sitter universe is a good counter-example to time-translational invariance.

Heck, even the FLRW metric is. At cosmological timescales that would certainly suggest that energy doesn’t always conserve - you might also ask where the energy in the CMBR went as it redshifted (that redshift being caused by properties of the FLRW metric).
